# Always show Pager on CGridView?

Tags: yii

I've build a CGridView menu, and I want to always display the pager 
(even when it's showing all the data and the navigation is not needed) 
This is the current code I have:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',
        array('dataProvider'=>$search,
              'columns' => $columns,
              'itemsCssClass' => 'list_table',
              'template' => '{pager}{summary}{items}',
              'pager' => array(
                  'cssFile'=>false,
                  'class'=>'CLinkPager',
                  'firstPageLabel' => '&lt;&lt;',
                  'prevPageLabel' => '&lt;',
                  'nextPageLabel' => '&gt;',
                  'lastPageLabel' => '&gt;&gt;',
                  'header' => '',
                  'footer' => $footer_btns,
                  ),
              'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
            ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by overriding the renderPager() method -- however, it seems that the pager gets put together in a few files so one way to do it by only overriding one class would be to:

override zii.widgets.grid.CGridView to add your custom renderPager() method with something like:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');
class MyGrid extends CGridView {
    public function renderPager() { ... }
}
```

the default renderPager() function is [here](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.8/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php#239).

What you want to do is look for the line that tests for pager content:

```
if($pager['pages']->getPageCount()>1) {
```

and change the "else" statement to put in your default "empty" pager content, which could use the same `<ul>` structure. Since you are not providing any navigation for the blank view, you don't need to worry about that data if this is used in multiple places. That could look something like:

```
else {
        echo '<div class="'.$this->pagerCssClass.'">';
        ## YOUR CUSTOM "EMPTY PAGER" HTML HERE ##
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

You might need to define a couple extra css classes as well. On pages where only part of the pagination is showing (e.g., the first and last page), you can use CSS to redefine the ".hidden" class(es).

Comment: how can i use CListPager and CLinkPager both in pagination, is there any parameter, or call it in the renderPager() function. And how to get rid of "go to page:" label for CLinkPager.